# How to fit a lot of x labels or space out x labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to space out so that each x label is more distinguishable? 
I feel like this question has been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer. I believe the graph needs to be bigger for this to work, is their a way to make the graph bigger within Rstudio? or make the text smaller

My code so far :

```
bar_plt = ggplot(data, aes(fct_infreq(Event))) + geom_bar(fill = "dodgerblue", width = .4) +
                 xlab("Event Names") + ylab("Number of Observations") + coord_flip()
```

TIA

[image: is there a way to space out the x label so it is more distinguishable?]

Comment: Are you asking how to make the plot bigger and the text smaller, or are you asking if there is some way to "fit" the labels better other than doing those two things?

Comment: i would prefer for a way to fit the labels better. If not then I want to make the plot bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about working with labels in this way (sorry for the fake data, but I have not got a sample of your):

```
library(ggplot2)
# numbers
set.seed(1)
y<-sample(1:30, 500, TRUE)

# very long and numerous labels
x <-  paste(sample(letters[1:22], 500, TRUE),sample(letters[1:2], 500, TRUE),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
data <- data.frame(x,y)

# simple ggplot barplot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()

# play with the size to have a fitting dimension
p <- p + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black",  size=8))

# you can also abbreviate the labels if necessary
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
p
```

Your plot could be something like:

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

# data
set.seed(1)
Events <-  paste(sample(letters[1:22], 500, TRUE),sample(letters[1:2], 500, TRUE),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
data <- data.frame(Events)

bar_plt <- ggplot(data, aes(fct_infreq(Events))) + geom_bar(fill = "dodgerblue", width = .4) + coord_flip()
bar_plt <- bar_plt + xlab("Event Names") + ylab("Number of Observations")
bar_plt <- bar_plt + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black",  size=8))
bar_plt <- bar_plt + scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
bar_plt
```

[image]